# In-House Enterprise Distribution: iOS 7 device "Unable to Download App", iOS 8 device has no issue

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution, enterprise-distribution

I have been developing/distributing an iOS iPad app for over a year, but very recently have encountered a problem. When I run my code on both my iOS 8 iPad and iOS 7 iPad, there are no issues. I then switch to my Enterprise Dist provisioning profile and create an archive. I update my manifest.plist, correctly update the version number, md5 values, etc. I upload everything as usual and when I download the app on my iOS 8 device, it installs fine. But now when I try and download on my iOS 7 device, it says "Waiting..." for a few seconds, then I get the error message, "Unable to Download App "MyAppName" could not be downloaded at this time".

I don't understand why I've never had this issue in the past, and it makes no sense to me why it installs fine on the other device.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

iOS 7 iPad version: **7.0.4**
iOS 8 iPad version: **8.3**
Xcode version: **6.3.2**

iOS 7 iPad console logs:
`Jun  2 12:37:47 Kats-iPad wifid[70] <Notice>: WiFi:[454966667.548617]: Client itunesstored set type to background application
Jun  2 12:37:47 Kats-iPad wifid[70] <Notice>: WiFi:[454966667.550120]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: networkd apsd itunesstored 
Jun  2 12:37:47 Kats-iPad wifid[70] <Notice>: WiFi:[454966667.551294]: Already connected to softwareCompany.
Jun  2 12:37:48 Kats-iPad itunesstored[166] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.myCompany.myApp (Placeholder) withPhase:0
Jun  2 12:37:48 Kats-iPad lsd[135] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installState for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> to LSInstallStateWaiting
Jun  2 12:37:48 Kats-iPad lsd[135] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.000000> to 0
Jun  2 12:37:48 Kats-iPad lsd[135] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.myCompany.myApp
Jun  2 12:37:48 Kats-iPad itunesstored[166] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.myCompany.myApp.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache`

**UPDATE:** For 2 days I could not install the app. Today for the heck of it I tried again after making no changes, and it worked! Very strange. Still have no idea why it wouldn't install.

Comment: Sometimes, when a failed install did happen (the install icon remains greyed and cannot be removed), I saw next installs of the same app to failed too. Restarting completely the device can help.

Comment: @NicolasBuquet I never restarted the device, I figured deleting the greyed icon would be enough (I was able to remove it the same as any successfully installed app). If this issue comes up again that's the first thing I'll try! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with one app a few months ago.

For some reason on iOS 7 devices I was not able to install, but after a complete reboot of one device it worked. Really don't why as you, maybe something wrong happens on operating system side.

So the workaround for me was **reboot the device** but I don't know why this worked for me and maybe it's not a solution for everyone.

Comment: If this issue happens again I will definitely try a reboot. I never restarted my device though, so this still remains a mystery why it wouldn't install for days when it was presumably the same scenario as today.

Comment: It would be nice know why this happens, If I discover something I'll update my answer for sure! :)